# Datepicker com multiplas datas arrastando o mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-plugins

Alguém conhece algum plugin que trabalha junto com o Datepicker (jqueryUI), onde eu consiga selecionar várias datas, arrasto o mouse com o botão clicado sobre o calendário e seleciono quantas datas quiser, depois só soltar o mouse e as datas estão selecionadas?

Comment: Veja se [esse plugin](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#disable-dates-demo) lhe ajuda em algo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Randrade mas não funciona do jeito que quero, precisaria poder arrastar o mouse e pegar um período de datas, ou mesmo usar o shift.